# How many .hbm files are needed to represent Hibernate Inheritance?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

In order to represent inheritance how many hbm files are needed?

How do I represent the relationship between base and subclasses in the subclass hbm file?

I want hbm and pojo class of super and sub class.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-subclass

Use the "extends" attribute of the "subclass", "joined-subclass" or "union-subclass" elements.  You can put all classes in the same .hbm file or split them into separate files if you wish.